# Inconsistent accessibility support for gear icons

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, badge-progress, accessibility

[image: Profile page with three gear icons: first tracks the next tag badge, second appears on the left of the next tag badge, third tracks the next badge]
All gear icons highlighted in the screenshot above offer a similar experience: you can click on it and a "window" opens.

However there are subtle differences that *may* have an impact for keyboard-only and/or screenreader users.

The gear icons circled in green (track badges or privileges):

- ✅ Can be tabbed into
- ✅ Once in focus, hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will open the "window"
- ✅ Hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> will dismiss the "window"

The gear icon circled in red (track the next tag badge):

- ❌ Can be tabbed into
- ❌ Once in focus, hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will open the "window"
- ❌ Hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> will dismiss the "window"

Here's a screencast highlighting the difference in the tab navigation:

[image: Animated picture showing that the next tag badge cannot be tabbed into]

Comment: Ironically (for a question tagged accessibility) I have no idea what you’re talking about because I can’t see the images (Imgur may be blocked on my current network). Can you describe the images better? Where do the gears appear?

Comment: @Laurel Good call! I added placeholder texts to my images and named the gear icons in the post. Hopefully that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: That’s great except I can’t see the descriptions unless I look at the markdown , which looks like a bug. It’s weird because I could see “insert image description here” in the previous revision and now I just see blank boxes.